# Как создать объект Bitmap с BitmapFactory.Options имея обьект URI?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть объект URI который содержит в себе адрес загружаемого изображения.
Мне надо получить изображение и изменить его размер.

Есть объект полученный как входной параметр

```
  private final Uri mUri;

  public LoadEditSaveImageTask(Uri uri) {
        this.mUri = uri;
    }
```

Создаю новый объект c options:

```
  BitmapFactory.Options optionsBitmap = new BitmapFactory.Options();
  optionsBitmap.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
```

Дальше открываю поток:

```
FileInputStream fis = (FileInputStream) 
mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(mUri);
```

Получаю из потока размеры картинки, при этом не загружаю в память:

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, optionsBitmap);
```

Далее определяю новый требуемый размер картинки с помощью метода inSampleSize:

```
optionsBitmap.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(optionsBitmap, NEED_WIDTH_IMAGE, NEED_HEIGHT_IMAGE)
```

Пытаюсь создать Bitmap с новым размером. При этом из потока я благополучно получил размер картинки.

```
FileInputStream fis2 = (FileInputStream) 
mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(mUri);
Bitmap scaledImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis2,null,optionsBitmap);
```

Выдает ошибку **scaledImage равно null**. При этом если загружать без optionsBitmap, то картинка загружается.
Не могу понять где ошибка и почему не могу получить изображение.Подскажите пожалуйста.

Полный код метода:

```
private Bitmap checkANdScale() {

        Bitmap scaledImage = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options optionsBitmap = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        optionsBitmap.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = (FileInputStream) mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(mUri);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, optionsBitmap);
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
            optionsBitmap.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(optionsBitmap, NEED_WIDTH_IMAGE, NEED_HEIGHT_IMAGE);
            FileInputStream fis2 = (FileInputStream) mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(mUri);
            scaledImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis2,null,optionsBitmap);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return scaledImage;
    }
```

Comment: При втором декодировании используете тот же экземпляр потока? Но поток может быть прочитан один раз. Второй раз нужно запросить его по-новой.

Comment: Да вы правы, не правильно написал. Я открываю новый поток. Исправил код в вопросе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, разобрался. В коде я использовал options из старого потока.Создал новый options и все заработало.

```
BitmapFactory.Options optionsCreateBitmap = new BitmapFactory.Options();
FileInputStream fis2 = (FileInputStream) mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(mUri);
            optionsCreateBitmap.inSampleSize = 2;
            scaledImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis2, null, optionsCreateBitmap);
```